# RIAK riak-erlang-client Key values integerbinary (::<<_|128>>)

Tags: erlang, key-value, riak, riak-search

I try to use the okeuday/uuid lib to generate a <<_|128>> V4 UUID and use that as my RIAK Key to store data.

I use the git://github.com/basho/riak-erlang-client.git master Version.

When i use the binary int as key no data is stored and i got no error.
When i modify it as a binary string uuid:uuid_to_string(uuid:get_v4()),
my code works and i can store data.

I started new buckets to avoid keytype missmatches.

According to the basho manuals i can use any binary value as KEY ???

I am wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry -> found the error in my code...
I tried the riakc_poolboy lib but this lib was not able to handle some BucketTypeAndBucket tuples -> and could rec it after detailed stacktraceanalysis.

So if you read this -> you could use <<_|128>> as key with the riak-erlang-client. But i found the stringified version humanreadable to compare esp. in development -> maybe it`s better to use the binarie val for production..... any suggestions.

Thanx to the Riak-Team for this DB ....